# Sending and receiving plain text with TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener

I want to send this string through TCP connection:

`TR220,2,A10000XX,3545.1743,5119.5794,001.0,1503,52:56:16,2012/09/13,0,0,0,0,0,V,000,0,0,0,,+989123456789,*`

I am using this code to send the text:

```
string uri = "http://localhost:1414";
String record = "TR220,2,A10000XX,3545.1743,5119.5794,001.0,1503,52:56:16,2012/09/13,0,0,0,0,0,V,000,0,0,0,,+989123456789,*";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] postBytes = GetBytes(record);
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
```

and GetBytes method:

```
private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

After sending this Request, In the other side app, I get this String:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nHost: localhost:1414\r\nContent-Length: 212\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n
```

using this block of code:

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1414);
listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
listenThread.Start();
```

and ListenForClients method (some code omitted for clarity):

```
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
byte[] message = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while (true)
{
    bytesRead = 0;
    try { bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096); }
    catch { break; }
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    String data = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
    MessageReceived(data);
}
```

My question is why sent and received strings are not the same?

Comment: Any reason why you need to use HTTP on the send side?  Will you be hitting other servers which are actually HTTP servers?

Comment: I used the exact same code you did and received both the header and the body.  The HTTPWebRequest class will always add the HTTP header as this is part of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you know what you are doing? You are sending HTTP Packets to a raw TCP socket, off course you are going to get HTTP protocol strings around your true payload. Use the same kind of sockets on both ends or you will go insane eventually.

This is slightly old but seems good enough for what you need, as always: Google is you friend.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C

As for why a TCP socket is receiving an HTTP connection without a hitch? HTTP is run over TCP, it's just a formal protocol on top of it.